# How Do I get value from sql search based on the start and end dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Personnel Roles Table  where employees are assigned  daily roles or roles with specific start and end dates.
Managers have asked for a sort of manpower plan table which lists an employee’s  daily role and this how I generate the table

```
private string CreateHTMLTable(Int32 month)
{
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    System.Data.DataTable dtAllStaff = new System.Data.DataTable();
    //get all staff
    PersonelApplication.Classes.PersonelClass PersonnelClass = new PersonelClass();

    dtAllStaff = PersonnelClass.GetAllPersonel();

    //create manpower data table
    System.Data.DataTable dtManPowerDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();

    //create montlhy dt
    //get number of days in month
    int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, month);
    //get first day in month
    DateTime firstDayInMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, 1);
    //get last day in month
    DateTime lastDayInMonth = new DateTime();
    lastDayInMonth = firstDayInMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);



    //start table
    strBuilder.Append("<table>");

    //create header based on number of days in the month
    //append tr strat
    strBuilder.Append("<tr>");
    //add name header for personnle
    strBuilder.Append("<th>");
    strBuilder.Append("Staff");
    strBuilder.Append("</th>");
    for (int i = 1; i <= lastDayInMonth.Day; i++)
    {
        strBuilder.Append("<th>");
        strBuilder.Append(i.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString());
        strBuilder.Append("</th>");
    }

    //append tr end to header row
    strBuilder.Append("</tr>");
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

    sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionClass.CreateConnection.getConnectionString();
    using (sqlConn = ConnectionClass.CreateConnection.publicGetConn())
    {
        sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionClass.CreateConnection.getConnectionString();
        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {

                foreach (DataRow row in dtAllStaff.Rows)
                {
                    string personnelName = "";
                    string personnelCode = "";

                    Int32 personnelID = 0; ;

                    personnelCode = row[1].ToString();
                    strBuilder.Append("<tr>");
                    strBuilder.Append("<td>");

                    strBuilder.Append(personnelCode);
                    strBuilder.Append("</td>");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= lastDayInMonth.Day; i++)
                    {
                        //here get the each employee's planned role as well
                        //as actual role 
                    }
                    strBuilder.Append("</tr>");
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //pouplate later
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }

    //end table
    strBuilder.Append("</table>");


    return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

My issue is the SQL function which will return the employees role for a particular day.

```
--actual end date for this role is '08-18-2012'
declare @sdate date
set @sdate= '08-14-2012'
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date,startdate,101)
    ,CONVERT(date,EndDate,101)
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
     ,fk_PersonelID
     ,fk_RoleID
  FROM [dbo].JobRolesTable
  where @sdate between StartDate and EndDate 
    and fk_PersonelID = 40
```

But If I do a search for the next day which is the '08-15-2012’,I get nada
Bascially I want to return an employee’s role on any day of the month and ‘na’ if there’s none
I don’t want to use a cursor for this but is there another way I can achieve this

Comment: "@sdate"? It need to be a table field. Then it will provide result against your query.

Comment: @DarshanJoshi the table has columns named StartDate and EndDate (those aren't variables). Please look closer at the query, it seems valid to me.

Comment: You say the EndDate for this role is 08-18-2012 (stop using that format please, use YMD), but what is the StartDate?

Comment: I suspect that @sdate will not be considered in date-range, and all the data will be shown. I have a tested it on mock table. Only the table field against which where clause is defined, is producing accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sdate DATE = '20120814';

SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE,StartDate,101) -- what is the purpose of 101 here?
    ,CONVERT(DATE,EndDate,101)  -- what is the purpose of 101 here?
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
     ,fk_PersonelID
     ,fk_RoleID
  FROM [dbo].JobRolesTable
  WHERE @sdate >= StartDate 
    AND @sdate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate) 
    AND fk_PersonelID = 40;
```

Comment: @SpaceghostAli it does not do anything if StartDate and EndDate are datetime columns. Those are usually used for converting to/from strings.

Comment: 101 specifices the US Date Format

Comment: @NapoleonOkunna if StartDate and EndDate are already datetime values, there is no "format"

Comment: @AaronBertrand Was doing some testing to see if there was any issues with the formats

Comment: I was working of an old backup of the database,restored a newer back and it started work,appratnelty the older backup had erroneous data.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably populating your parameters incorrectly.

If your query is of the form

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE (@SearchDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND Id=@Id
```

(which yours appears to be), then it will return the correct values from the db as long as the dates are being specified correctly.

Can you show the code where you're actually attempting to use the SqlConnection that you're opening in the posted code?

Comment: The problem is @ the SQL end,I have written the code for the actual connection.Was testing the query before I actually wrote the code itself.